# Styling list items, replacing bullet with fontawesome

Tags: css, html, font-awesome

I have to create a list like this

[image]

I have tried to replace bullet with fontawesome icon which worked but I am getting something like this

[image]

Notice, there is a spacing difference between both of them. My CSS is

```
.custom_list li {
 line-height:2em;
 padding-left:0px;
 padding-top:5px;
 padding-bottom:5px;
 font-size:14px;
 list-style-type:none;
 list-style:none;
}
.custom_list li:before {
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 content: "\f192";
 color: black;
 margin-right:15px;
}
```

HTML is

```
<ul class="custom_list" >
  <li>Medical Student Education</li>
  <li>Resident Training Education (Medicine, Osteopathic, Pharmacy)</li>
  <li>Fellowship Training Education (all medical subspecialties)</li>
  <li>Nursing Student Training Education</li>
  <li>Nurse Practitioner Education</li>
  <li>Nurse Continuing Education</li>
  <li>Physician Continuing Medical Education</li>
</ul>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why aren't you doing it like this: http://fontawesome.io/examples/#list ?

Comment: I tried that but still I get the spacing issue, I don't want the content to come under the bullet

Comment: See in the second and third point in the list, the content is under the bullet , i want it to be like the first image

Comment: Strange, when I add extra text into that example I don't get the spacing issue you describe. Try it, you'll see what I mean - if it works there it should work anywhere. Unless you have some other custom styles over-qualifying the fontawesome list styles which could be negating this behaviour.

Comment: I've demonstrated this behaviour in a JSFiddle, just for you :) Take a look --> https://jsfiddle.net/3L766kdo/4/ For the sake of demonstration, you can edit that content directly to add or remove text.

Comment: I guess something else in the template is causing this. I will update when I fix it

Comment: Well, when you fix it you won't have the problem anymore. Go with what clearly works and just stick with fontawesome's bespoke built list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.custom_list li {
 line-height:2em;
 padding-left:0px;
 padding-top:5px;
 padding-bottom:5px;
 font-size:14px;
 list-style-type:none;
 list-style:none;
 display: table-row;
}
.custom_list li:before {
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 content: "\f192";
 color: black;
 margin-right:15px;
 display: table-cell;
}
```

You need to change your list format to table

Answer (score 2):

Beware in font awesome 5, you will need a different font name,

```
.custom_list li:before {
 font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.custom_list li {
 line-height:2em;
 padding-left:20px;
 padding-top:5px;
 padding-bottom:5px;
 font-size:14px;
 list-style-type:none;
 list-style:none;
}
.custom_list li:before {
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
 content: "\f192";
 color: black;
 margin-right:15px;
 position:absolute;
  left:40px
}
```